# How to retrieve group members from a group which are only other groups

Tags: soql, governorlimits

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, Type, RelatedId,
        (
            SELECT UserOrGroupId
            FROM GroupMembers
            WHERE UserOrGroupId IN (
                SELECT Id
                FROM Group
                WHERE UserOrGroupId IN (SELECT Id FROM Group)
            )
        )
    FROM Group
```

I was using the above quite happily on the API however we need to move this over to APEX and that doesn't support nesting semi joins how else can I restrict GroupMembers to only return group members related to this group that are groups and not users. I cannot filter after the fact as there are too many users, and I will hit my governor limits.

EDIT:
I have tried going from the membership out using the below but the issue is the last level of groups don't have group memberships therefore don't show up. As I don't want to query every single group and group membership this isn't really practical.

```
SELECT Id, Group.Id, Group.Name, Group.DeveloperName,
    Group.OwnerId, Group.Type, Group.RelatedId, Group.Email,
    Group.DoesSendEmailToMembers, Group.DoesIncludeBosses, Group.QueueRoutingConfigId,
    UserOrGroupId
FROM GroupMember
WHERE UserOrGroupId IN (
    SELECT Id
    FROM Group
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, couldn't it just be:

```
SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, Type, RelatedId,
    (
        SELECT UserOrGroupId
        FROM GroupMembers
        WHERE UserOrGroupId IN ( SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Regular' )
    )
FROM Group
```

Comment: Nope can't have semi joins in child queries in apex that's what I was doing before it works if you call the restpoint query but not in apex it's self

Comment: @KarlLivesey This works for me in apex code.  What error are you getting when you use this?

Comment: hmmmm odd it was giving me that error when I was trying to deploy that I couldn't do that in child queries hence why I went on this adventure

Comment: I think yours had an extra sub query